# Why is stack not auto detecting my module?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to write a script that uses Diagrams but the stack package detection feature is confusing me. I have two files and when the support module imports SVGFonts stack doesn't add it to the list of modules that are found. Instead, it's hidden. When the import is in the main file, however, it downloads it and finds it for the build just fine.

Main.hs

```
-- stack --resolver lts-19.0 script

{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}

import Diagrams.Prelude
import MyMod (val)

import Diagrams.Backend.SVG

main = print val
```

MyMod.hs

```
module MyMod where

import Diagrams.Backend.SVG

val = 1
```

And I am getting this error

```
    Could not load module ‘Diagrams.Backend.SVG’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘diagrams-svg-1.4.3.1’.
    You can run ‘:set -package diagrams-svg’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Diagrams.Backend.SVG (loadFont)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I get stack to automatically find that I need SVGFonts and import it properly without adding the import to my main file?

Comment: Can you share the `.cabal` file?

Comment: There isn't one. These are the only two files in the project. It's a script.

Comment: Seems like you ought to list your dependencies via the `--package` option: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#writing-independent-and-reliable-scripts

Comment: Why does stack's auto module detection understand Diagrams.Prelude in the main file without a --package declaration but it doesn't see Diagrams.Backend.SVG in the sub module? I couldn't see this behavior in the documentation.

Comment: Actually I'm surprised that the script interpreter accepts local "sub modules" at all. I'm not convinced that this is an intended feature.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues to inquire further about this.